# String Comparison to track Changeset

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I am working in an asp.net project(WebForms,C#,.net 4.O).

I have a string list which is populated dynamically based on some criterion's,it can have any number of string elements depending on the scenario.These string elements are basically some lengthy sentences. For example,take the following as sample list

```
List<string> stringColl = new List<string>();
stringColl.Add("I am joining");
stringColl.Add("I not joining");
stringColl.Add("joining");
stringColl.Add("I may not be joining");
```

Now i need to track the changes in the final entry in the List by comparing with the other entries.
The final entry is treated as the final version,i.e if anything is added/removed from the earlier versions that should be Stored in another List.

In the above example "may" is the word which is additional,so this needs to be added in a result string.Also "am" is the word which is missing from the earlier versions , so that also should be stored in another result List.

Can someone help me in achieving this?

Comment: Think along the lines of a [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)

Comment: I am not doing a file comparison here!

Comment: Diff is char sequence comparison. Not only file comparison. The comment is only to give you direction, cause your question doesn't show much research effort